# Why would download history appear blank even though I save a file?

Tags: terminal, safari, monterey

I ran this command in Terminal on Monterey 12.5.1:

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV* 'select LSQuarantineDataURLString from LSQuarantineEvent' > ~/Downloads/downloadhistory.txt
```

It saved the file as expected, and despite me running it again in terminal after saving a jpeg file, it was still blank.

Why is this?

I disabled Spotlight, could that be a reason?

Why would the output of this file be empty even after saving 4 JPEG files from [www.bbc.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk), normally this command would display a list of files saved from URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since Monterey 12.4 it's not being recorded.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer with details why you believe that to be the case?